# Wordpress: print excerpt of the post

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to wordpress, but my brother wants wordpress site so I'm making him a custom wordpress theme and I'm stuck at trying to get excerpt of the post. I have read documentation and tried changing excerpt length but it doesn't seem to respond in either case, the output is basically the_content of the post.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you really add an excerpt to the post in the edit page? An excerpt is a separate piece of text.

Wordpress shows the post content when the excerpt is empty. It will take the first 55 words of the content. ([source](https://wordpress.org/support/article/excerpt/))

When editing a post, you have a separate input box for excerpts. Look under screen options if it's hidden.

You can open the screen options on the edit page at the top of your screen. There is a small popup called 'screen options'.

Comment: I have content 250 words long, so it ought to show less... I know that I can manually add excerpt in wordpress, but I want it to show first 55 words of the post.